# Sequel to Robert Reed's The Well of Stars?

Tags: robert-reed

I loved reading *Marrow* and *The Well of Stars* and always felt like it was a trilogy. Is there a sequel? Is one planned?

Comment: Isn't this a simple reference question that you could look up on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Donald.McLean You can look up published works on Wikipedia, or more reliably for SF authors on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?Robert_Reed). Sequel *plans* might be harder to find, but you can't do much better than the author's easily-found, well-maintained website.

Comment: I'm just saying - the FAQ gives this example of an off topic question: Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?

Comment: sorry this has caused problems, however...
1) before asking this question I found 3 other sequel questions (from a title search) so there is a precedent. 
2) I was aware of go-to sources such as author's website and wikipedia. I was hoping that I missed an obscure reference I couldn't find with searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's good or bad timing, but Robert Reed's website has just (April 20) posted a piece where he talks about what happened with the sequel, the vagaries of the publishing industry, and the future novels set in the Marrow universe that he's working on now. You might have missed it if you had only checked there initially and not also asked the question here (or if you went to the site right after it was suggested above).

http://www.robertreedwriter.com/frombob.html

If you're not already aware of it, his novelette "Hatch" in the anthology *The New Space Opera* (vol. 1) takes place quite some time after the events of *The Well of Stars*. It doesn't feature any of the characters from the books, it's about those trapped outside the hull.

Answer (score 2):

As of date, there is no third book in this series.
But, there is however more to read in the same universe.
*Marrow* and *The Well of Stars* belong to the *Great Ship universe* as Robert Reed calls it. The following list is all his work in this universe, and the three last ones are forthcoming, the author has not said what these are.

- The Remoras [nv] [May 1994]
- Aeon's Child [na] [Nov 1995]
- Marrow [na] [Jul 1997] *
- Marrow [novel] [Jul 2000] [novel-length expansion of the Jul 1997 novella] *
- Night of Time [ss] [May 2003]
- River of the Queen [nv] [Feb 2004]
- Mere [nv] [Sep 2004] [stand-alone chapbook]
- ["Improbable Journeys" - author essay about the origin and background of the Marrow universe - included in the Mere chapbook]
- The Well of Stars [novel] [Dec 2004]
- Camouflage [na] [May 2005]
- ["Afterward" to The Cuckoo's Boys collection includes extended notes on "Night of Time" and "River of the Queen"]
- Hoop-of-Benzene [nv] [Jun 2006]
- Rococo [na] [Jun 2006]
- Hatch [nv] [Jun 2007]
- The Caldera of Good Fortune [nv] [Sep 2007]
- The Man With the Golden Balloon [na] [February 2008]
- Alone [na] [August 2010]
- Eater-of-Bone [na] [forthcoming]
- Katabasis [na] [forthcoming]
- Noumenon [nv] [forthcoming]

[* Please note: The novella "Marrow" and the expanded novel Marrow differ dramatically. Readers should be aware that it is the novel Marrow that matches the continuity of later stories in this sequence.]

Reference: http://www.robertreedwriter.com